# Spring DataSourceTransactionManager does not commit

Tags: java, database, spring, transactions, transactionmanager

I think my transaction manager does not work at all. On insert to the database auto-increment value increases, but no new data added.
I define transaction manager, jdbc template and data source programmatically.
Transaction manager:

```
@Bean("txManager")
public DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager(
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(basicDataSource);;
}
```

JDBC template:

```
@Bean
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate(
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(basicDataSource);
}
```

DataSource:

```
@Bean
public BasicDataSource basicDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    // ...
    dataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);
    // ...
    return dataSource;
}
```

Service:

```
@Override
@Transactional("txManager")
public User register(RegistrationForm registrationForm) {
    User userToRegister = UserMapper.registrationFormToUser().apply(registrationForm);
    encryptPassword(userToRegister);
    return userDao.insert(userToRegister);
}
```

Here is debug log:

```
[DEBUG] [2018-12-07 10:37:35] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
[DEBUG] [2018-12-07 10:37:35] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
[DEBUG] [2018-12-07 10:37:35] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] JdbcTemplate - Executing SQL update and returning generated keys
[DEBUG] [2018-12-07 10:37:35] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO "user" (first_name, last_name, email, password, role_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[DEBUG] [2018-12-07 10:37:35] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
[DEBUG] [2018-12-07 10:37:35] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just a hunch, but have you just try to set `dataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit` to `true` ? Or do a manual commit after the insert.

Comment: It commits with defaultAutoCommit true, but if some exception occurred, there is no rollback operation done.

Comment: Did you enable transaction management in Spring config?

Comment: Where I should enable it (programmatically)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are missing @EnableTransactionManagement on your Spring configuration class